# store data partition of an Android device for later flashing

Tags: rom-flashing

Does anybody know of a procedure where you can essentially take the /data partition off of a device and flash it to another one?

(IE, to generate a userdata.img file from a device.)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a nandroid backup. ClockworkMod does it well. That creates an yaffs2 img of the data & datadata partitions.

I think this might not be a great solution though, if you want to flash to another device. This will contain all the info in data (or data/data) and may cause issues if the version of android is not the same, or even if the device is different.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. The device Android version thing won't be an issue, I want to reset a phone to a default state that includes some settings and an email account. .. so the image will be going back onto the same phone and system image it started out on, or another one that is exactly the same.

Comment: titanium backup (if you are rooted) would be a good option too. it lets you pick what what you want to back up.